# C# API for Task Scheduler 2.0

Tags: c#

Does anyone have any recommendations for a .NET c# wrapper for the (COM based) Task Scheduler 2.0 API ?

Couldnt find anything using Google.

(I am aware there are .net based schedulers such as Quartz.net, but I need the fully functioned GUI in the windows Scheduler)

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 36, accepted):

See the following project on GitHub:

https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler

Comment: Yea thanks.  Thats exactly what I was looking for.  Somehow missed it when I searched for it.

Comment: +1 exactly what i needed, i also searched a bit around until i decided to make a search here before posting the same question as Matt

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Task Scheduler is painful and the command line (schtasks) looks even worse. This API is working great so far. Thank you!

Comment: After successfully installing assemblies through Nugget it does not recognize **TaskService** in code. What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 11):

If you dont want to use any third party wrapper then below is the sample code to schedule task.Code works in Windows 7.

```
//create task service instance
ITaskService taskService = new TaskSchedulerClass();
taskService.Connect();
ITaskDefinition taskDefinition = taskService.NewTask(0);
taskDefinition.Settings.Enabled = true;
taskDefinition.Settings.Compatibility = _TASK_COMPATIBILITY.TASK_COMPATIBILITY_V2_1;

//create trigger for task creation.
ITriggerCollection _iTriggerCollection = taskDefinition.Triggers;
ITrigger _trigger = _iTriggerCollection.Create(_TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_TIME);
_trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss");
_trigger.EndBoundary = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss");
_trigger.Enabled = true;

///get actions.
IActionCollection actions = taskDefinition.Actions;
_TASK_ACTION_TYPE actionType = _TASK_ACTION_TYPE.TASK_ACTION_EXEC;

//create new action
IAction action = actions.Create(actionType);
IExecAction execAction = action as IExecAction;
execAction.Path = @"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe";
ITaskFolder rootFolder = taskService.GetFolder(@"\");

//register task.
rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("test", taskDefinition, 6, null, null, _TASK_LOGON_TYPE.TASK_LOGON_NONE, null);
```

Comment: From where did you get the `ITaskService`, `TaskSchedulerClass`, `ITaskDefinition`, `ITriggerCollection`, `ITrigger`, `IActionCollection`, `IAction`, `IExecAction`, and `ITaskFolder`?  The assembly with those classes and interfaces is not readily visible in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Nevermind - I found the "taskschd.dll" file and after letting Visual Studio generate an Interop wrapped, was able to import it into my project.  If only I could do the same with the PowerShell ISE and have it deploy to the destination target machines...

Comment: You saved my day, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Is the command line good enough?

`at 23:39 /every:wednesday defrag c:`

Comment: Or better yet its successor, `schtasks`

Answer (score 0):

You can get fully functioned GUI through following Nuget command.

PM> Install-Package TaskSchedulerEditor

Comment: why would you install a package with a gui if windows has a gui build especially for this `taskschd.msc /s`

Comment: Here TaskSchedulerEditor is name of COM wrapper designed to used in C# code to access windows task scheduler GUI.

Comment: This is the nuget package for http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/