# Task scheduler on windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I have some task/ program to run on an windows XP machine at some specific dates. The dates are stored inside a .dbf and the dates will be dynamic. How can I schedule the tasks on the specific dates?

I am planning to write another program (perhaps c# service) to run cmd with the command `at` to create tasks in task scheduler. Is there any ways to specify all the dates into one task? And will it be possible to link the task scheduler with a DB? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# API for Task Scheduler 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977801/c-sharp-api-for-task-scheduler-2-0)

Comment: Actually the operating computer will be upgrade to windows 7 after some months.... so I was wondering if there was any really simple and quick work around the issue.... And as there seems to be no, I guess I'll wait for the windows upgrade......thanks

Comment: Why don't you create a c# service for windows ?you can also create a scheduler task to run a c# program every hour and in c# check if its the right time to run the main script .

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a C# wrapper, that is script callable, that will work with the Task Scheduler on both XP and Windows 7. The download and source code is at https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com. With that wrapper, you can create a task that executes an action that has multiple triggers. Those triggers can be set for single days, weeks, months, etc. with different repetition patterns. There are many samples both in the documentation and discussion areas to help with your coding.