# Window schedule task status api

Tags: c#

Is there a class for schedule task status so I can call and get the status as a collection of schedule task status objects?  I know I can use command line like: "schtasks /query /fo LIST /v", but I have to parse the string and get what I need.

Comment: See http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Comment: Did you try googling for "Scheduled Tasks API"? The first two results are the API, the next are similar questions and references to the Task Scheduler project on Codeplex

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# API for Task Scheduler 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977801/c-sharp-api-for-task-scheduler-2-0)

Comment: Why don't you change the title to a proper one. Because *"Window schedule task status api"* doesn't sounds like a question at all!!

Comment: I was hoping for something straight out of .net library.